# How to send header with GET in ChromeDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, get, selenium-chromedriver

How can I send the a parameter in the header when running a GET using ChromeDriver?

Ex:

```
@Test
public void testGoogleSearch() {

  // add header param 'Authorization' : 'Bearer Xxddxxx'
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");

}
```